# I've exceeded my unlock attempts (10). Is there any way to unlock my phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sim-unlocking

Due to AT&T being a *horrible* company, I believe the customer "service" has led me through more than my allotted attempts at unlocking my phone. Because my phone was refurbished, the attempts may have already all have been used. I believe my phone is now "Hard Locked"

Anyhow, my contract is over but I'd love to keep using my galaxy s3 on a different network. Is there any way to reset the unlock counter so I can unlock my phone? I'm willing to pay for an unlock code or go through the process of rooting my phone if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset?

Comment: What exaclty is locked? The SIM card? If this is the case, you should be able to simply remove it. The SIM card itself won't be any good.

Answer (score 1):

If your sim card is locked then you can just remove it and put another one in.
If the phone itself is locked, you can do a factory-reset by using the recovery, hold power, home, volume-up until you get to the recovery screen and choose the factory reset option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact AT&T and request your puk1 and puk2 codes (not to be mistaken for a 'pac' code) This will be free to do. Now it depends on what/how you have locked your phone as to which of the puk codes you need to use.